# How to sort one column in data frame by sets of rows in another column in pandas? python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, data-analysis

Suppose the dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   DEPTH  VARIABLE
111  3      x
111  4      x
111  1      x
111  2      x
222  1      x
222  4      x
222  2      x
222  3      x
```

I'm trying to sort DEPTH in ascending order, with the variables sorted to match DEPTH too, but without changing the order of the ID column, so that I get the following result:

```
ID   DEPTH  VARIABLE
111  1      x
111  2      x
111  3      x
111  4      x
222  1      x
222  2      x
222  3      x
222  4      x
```

Comment: `df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'DEPTH'])` ?  or `df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'DEPTH']).reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: @HenryEcker - `reset_index()` might nor be required here.

Comment: That is true. Both options are good to include. Thank you @Utsav